# I cannot extract interface class on my ASP.net project (Visual Studio 2019)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have a LanguageRepository.cs class file:

```
public class LanguageRepository : ILanguageRepository
    {
        private readonly BookStoreContext _context = null;
        public LanguageRepository(BookStoreContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public async Task<int> AddNewLanguage(LanguageModel language)
        {
            var newLanguage = new Language()
            {
                Id = language.Id,
                Name = language.Name,
                Description = language.Description
            };
            await _context.Language.AddAsync(newLanguage);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return newLanguage.Id;
        }
        public async Task<List<LanguageModel>> GetLanguages()
        {
            return await _context.Language.Select(x => new LanguageModel()
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                Description = x.Description,
                Name = x.Name,
            }).ToListAsync();
        }
```

I want to extract Interface so I click **right mouse**->**Quick actions and refactorings...**->**extract interface**
Then system play with this window:

[image]

I click OK but ILanguageRepository.cs file not be generated and have an error when i select options "Add to current file".

> System.ArgumentException : textContainer is not a SourceTextContainer that was created from an ITextBuffer.
> Parameter name: textContainer
> at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Text.Extensions.GetTextBuffer(SourceTextContainer textContainer)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.VisualStudioDocumentNavigationService.NavigateToFileInWorkspace(DocumentId documentId,Workspace workspace,Func`2 getVsTextSpan,CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.VisualStudioDocumentNavigationService.TryNavigateToLocation(Workspace workspace,DocumentId documentId,Func`2 getTextSpanForMapping,Func`2 getVsTextSpan,OptionSet options,CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.VisualStudioDocumentNavigationService.TryNavigateToPosition(Workspace workspace,DocumentId documentId,Int32 position,Int32 virtualSpace,OptionSet options,CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CodeActions.DocumentNavigationOperation.Apply(Workspace workspace,CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CodeActions.CodeActionOperation.TryApply(Workspace workspace,IProgressTracker progressTracker,CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.CodeActions.CodeActionEditHandlerService.ProcessOperations(Workspace workspace,ImmutableArray`1 operations,IProgressTracker progressTracker,CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.CodeActions.CodeActionEditHandlerService.Apply(Workspace workspace,Document fromDocument,ImmutableArray`1 operations,String title,IProgressTracker progressTracker,CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.Suggestions.SuggestedAction.InvokeWorker(Func`1 getFromDocument,IProgressTracker progressTracker,CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.Suggestions.SuggestedAction.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.b__0()
> at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Extensions.IExtensionManagerExtensions.PerformAction(IExtensionManager extensionManager,Object extension,Action action)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)

I don't know why it not run.
Can you help me solve this problem?

Comment: What happens if you select Add to current file?

Comment: ILanguageRepository still could not generate. Before I created dotnet prj by vs code in Unbuntu. Is this proplem?

Comment: I get an error message when i select Add to current file

Comment: Re how you created the project. If there are project file differences (I don't use VS Code so am not sure) that may be the problem. Try creating directly in VS and/or post the code o your VS Code based project file.

Comment: i tried to create project by VS 2019 and it run well. thanks you.

Comment: Ok, will post it as an answer for others.

Answer (score 0):

There are differences between Visual Studio and Visual Studio code that make the direct port between the two somewhat problematic.

Create the new project directly into VS 2019 as you would normally and then the problem should be resolved.